# Is it possible to have more cliques than the number of nodes?

Tags: r, networking, clique

I have 27,000 nodes and 38,000 cliques, using `maximal.cliques()` in R.

Is it possible to have more cliques than the number of nodes? Why do so many nodes belong to more than 1 clique?

How can I restrict each node to only belong to 1 clique in R?

Comment: We don't know what package `maximal.cliques` comes from, but for the usual definition of cliques (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) a node can certainly belong to more than one.

Comment: You might look at this answer:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41947